# Visual Studio 2015 Add New Item Slow

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When i want to add a new item to a larger solution, the "Add New Item" popup window appears, but when typing in the name of the class/... it responds sooooo slow.

All the rest of the IDE is working as normal/expected, only this action has a super long lag.

Any idea where to start looking ?

Comment: Hey Ben...did you get anywhere with this?  I'm having the exact same problem.  I notice VS consuming 4% of the CPU, and the icons in the dialog load slowly.  And...I have 16GB of memory and an SSD for a C: drive.  It's ridiculous.

Comment: Hey Dan, i didn't get anywhere on this, i am hoping with the new Visual Studio "15" the problem will disappear

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my environment. A process called MsMpEng.exe was taking 100% of my disk usage when adding new files in Visual Studio. This process is the Windows Defender tool. I then went into te settings, and added under exclusions 2 exlusions:

- a folder exclusion to where my source files are
- a processes exclusion on devenv.exe

And now this works like a charm again. If you're Windows Defender is not active, you can start by looking in the resource monitor of windows in the disk section which process is using your disk, it could be some other scanner like McAfee, Norton, ...

Answer (score 0):

Click Small Icons instead of default Medium Icons.  Delay goes away.